TypeORM embedded entity shorthand select?
Recently, I got stuck scratching my head, because of how TypeORM behaves, given entities:
class Event extends BaseEntity {
    location: Address
}

class Address {
    @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
    city: string
}

Now if I want to select the event's city, apparently I can do it in two ways, which is confusing:
jobEventRepo.createQueryBuilder('jobEvent').select('jobEvent.location.city')
// or 
jobEventRepo.createQueryBuilder('jobEvent').select('jobEvent.city')

Both work the same, the first one was what I was using for long, but the second - shorthand way for doing the same I just discovered accidentally. Why do both work, is there a documentation for that, is one of those preferred?

My personal opinion is that for readability and clarity, it is better to use:
jobEventRepo.createQueryBuilder('jobEvent').select('jobEvent.location.city')

It also prevents some unexpected behaviour if someday you add city as a jobEvent property.
But it's not a strict best practice, check the official doc for a good example of using embedded entities https://typeorm.io/embedded-entities.

So for simplicity and convenience:
jobEventRepo.createQueryBuilder('jobEvent').select('jobEvent.city')

is also a good option. Everything depends on the particular case.
